# How to use custom image in gcloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, devops

I am quiet new to devops and I am trying to use a custom docker image that I have pushed to docker hub.

In my app.yaml I have replace `runtime: python` by `runtime:solalsab/clarins`. Is the approach correct and secondly I get an error message as follow:

`Value 'solalsab/clarins' for runtime does not match expression '^(?:((gs://[a-z0-9\-\._/]+)|([a-z][a-z0-9\-\.]{0,29})))$'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **app.yaml** it should be `runtime: custom` and `env: flex`.

The image should be defined in the **Dockerfile**: `FROM solalsab/clarins`

Check this [Custom Runtimes Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/quickstart).

Comment: Thanks I understand better. However not sure how to format my Dockerfile. The example furnished in the doc is not sufficient

Comment: In [Customizing the Python Runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/customizing-the-python-runtime) there is the example of Google's base image for Python Runtime which you can reference.

Comment: Can I ask you a last question ? What to put in "# Add the application source code." 
I wanted to do something like : "ADD ." as my Dockerfile is in my project itself but it requires 2 arguments

Comment: Sure :) I'm not an expert in Docker but it seems that the 2 arguments are `ADD <source> <destination>` so by doing `ADD . /app` (note the space between the dot and the "/app") you are copying everything that is in the same folder as your Dockerfile to the container's "/app" folder.

Comment: Thanks for your precious help !